# javascript: modify global variable from local variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables, global-variables, local-variables

I don't understand why in the function `change2`, the console doesn't output 2, but undefined?

```
var users = {a:1, b:2};

function change1(people){
    people.c = {};
    var C = people.c;
    setTimeout(function(){        
        C.number = 2;
    }, 1000);
}

function change2(people){
    people.c = {};
    var C = people.c;
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(C.number);
    }, 2000);
}

change1(users);
change2(users); // undefined, why not 2?
```

However, if I replace `C.number` by `people.c.number` within `setTimeout` of `change1`, it works(outputs 2), why? Don't they refer the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my explanation. In the change1 this creates a new object, lets call it object1, and keeps a reference in the **local** variable C:

```
  people.c = {};
  var C = people.c;
```

In change2 let change the name of C in B (for avoiding confusion)

```
people.c = {};
var B = people.c;
```

This creates another new object, lets call it object2, that overrides the reference in people.c (so people.c points to this new object) and stores a reference to the **local** variable B.

So the local variable C in change1 points to object1, the local variable B points to object2 and people.c points to object2.

```
C.number = 2
```

will define the number property of object1 in change1

meanwhile

```
console.log(B.number) //console.log(C.number) in the original code
```

will try to output the property of object2 that is undefined.

Basically C in change1 and C in change2 are pointing to two different objects. setTimeout does not have any effect in this.

Comment: How is people global scope? It's simply a function parameter. You're right in the explanations, but I don't understand how your answer is pertinent to the question. Here it's simply because OP reassigns an empty object to people.c (or users.c) in the `change2` function, as noted by @andrew_m...

Comment: @albanx Thanks for the clear explanation, I got it now.

Comment: It was really a nice hassle that make me really curios, so it was exercise even for me.

Answer (score 3):

Your change1 function assigns a new object to people.c and also stores it in local C variable.
Then in change2 you create another new object and store is in people.c.
So people.c (or rather users.c) holds now that second object.

After 1 second your change1 function creates a "number" property in the first object.
But people.c already holds a second object which stays not modified.
So after another 1 second change2 tries to find "number" property in the second object which do not have such property.

So in short you should remove

```
people.c = {};
```

from change2 so avoid overriding the people.c property.